# Intentionally cause a segfault under Ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby, segmentation-fault

What's the easiest way to cause a segfault intentionally in MRI Ruby 1.8.7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might check out [segfault4r](https://rubyforge.org/projects/segfault4r/) (it was last updated in 2007). You have to download and install the gem manually, as it's not available through RubyGems.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions everyone! I'm accepting this one because it's the easiest, but "mu is to short"'s answer was also a good one.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a bad C module that de-references a NULL pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs (and environment) you could get it running, find the interpreter's process ID and do:

```
$ kill -s SIGSEGV $pid
```

I just tried this on OSX with bash and it worked on an **ed(1)** (the one true text editor) process.

You could also run Ruby in a debugger and manually set a pointer or two to zero. One of the pointers inside a variable would do nicely. Of course, you'd probably need to have an interpreter built with debug symbols and you'd need to know a thing or two about the interpreter's internals.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this against a specific patchlevel, look at Ruby's [bug tracker](http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/) for bugs that were reported after that patchlevel was created that cause a segmentation fault. As you're looking at 1.8.7, you'll probably want to look at [those categorized as Ruby 1.8](http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-18) .

For example, for the version of Ruby (1.9) I have on my Windows machine, `Thread.kill(nil)` is [sufficient to cause a segfault](http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/4367), and I think it applies to Ruby 1.8 as well.

Comment: `Thread.kill(nil)` doesn't seem to work in 1.8.7. Thanks for the suggestion, though!

Comment: @Tyson: What's your Ruby's patchlevel? (Do `ruby -v` on the command line)